# Merging multiple WP databases into one for a multilanguage site prevents access to language-specific WP administration

Tags: database, dashboard, multi-language

My (inherited) WordPress website is setup like this:

- `example.com` is the main version of the site
- `en.example.com` is the English language version of the site. The subdomain's root is pointed to a en sub-directory within main website, like so `example.com/en`. That sub-directory has its own WordPress administration
- `de.example.com` is the German language version of the site. Like the English version, this one's root is also pointed to a sub-directory of the main website - `example.com/de`

On the old hosting, each of the websites had its own database.

Then the website was migrated to another host, and due to various limitations of that new host, I was unable to have more than one database. So, I did the following:

- merged all the databases into one
- the main site's database tables kept their `wp_` prefix
- the `en` and `de` tables received a prefix of `wp_<language>_` . For example `wp_en_posts`, or `wp_en_options`, or `wp_de_posts`, and so on
- the change was done in a text editor (a simple string replace)
- the entire contents of `en` and `de` SQL files were then copy/pasted into the SQL file for the main version of the website
- the changed SQL file was imported via phpMyAdmin (no errors)
- `$table_prefix` was adapted for `wp-config.php` for subdomains. For example, for `example.com/en/wp-config.php`, it was `$table_prefix = 'wp_en_';`
- nothing was changed in respective `.htaccess` files

After the changes, I tested if the site loaded as expected - it did, nothing was broken, and the correct content was displayed. I tested the login to the WP dashboard of the main website, and that was also working.

However, I can't access the WP dashboard for `en` and `de` versions of the website. I can go to `en.example.com/wp-admin`, fill out the login form, and submit it. Unfortunately, that only redirects me to `en.example.com`, and when I try to go to `en.example.com/wp-admin`, I get the error:

> Sorry, you are not allowed to access this page.

---

**Things I've tried**

I've checked the cookies created upon logging in to `en.example.com`, and they show the correct sub-domain.

I've also removed almost everything from `en.example.com/en/.htaccess` - the only lines left were the default WP entries. This was done just to eliminate `.htaccess` as the possible cause of the problem:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

`WP_HOME` and `WP_SITEURL` were not explicitly defined in appropriate `wp-config.php` language specific files, as I can access the `en.example.com` and `de.example.com` without any problems.

How can I resolve this issue, and access the language-specific WordPress dashboard?

Comment: it's possible the cookies of the main domain are interfering with the subdomains, it's also possible that by doing a text based search replace you corrupted PHP serialised strings ( they contain the length of the value so if the length changes but the numbers don't then they get broken by the search replace ). Note that a multisite was also an option, letting you use a single install for all 3 sites sharing the same users and code but with their own admin areas URLs and frontends

Comment: @TomJNowell So far, the cookies do not seem to be the culprit. Regarding the possible serialization issue, I decided to check if the tables were mentioned anywhere within the fields (manual check of some 370 entries) in both the original and the modified (prefaced tables) SQL file. There were no issues - unless they are somehow encrypted and then placed as an entry, table names were only mentioned in standard queries - `CREATE TABLE ...`, `INSERT INTO ...`, `ALTER TABLE ...`, etc. Regarding the multisite suggestion - I wasn't aware of that. Will look it up.

Comment: And the minute after I commented that, I ran into this: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/180167/2-website-1-database-local-to-online?rq=1 . Sure enough, after checking the tables mentioned (`wp_en_usermeta` and `wp_en_options`, I see that **there are** entries which I had missed). Will report if the linked question and answer have resolved the issue.

Comment: @TomJNowell Thank you for pointing me in the right direction - there were indeed entries in `wp_en_usermeta` and `wp_en_options`, and one missed entry in `wp_de_options` which were causing the issue I described. I'd gladly accept your answer if you were to post it. Or, if you think it's better - I could flag the question as a duplicate, because an identical (and resolved) issue exists [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/180167/2-website-1-database-local-to-online?rq=1).